# Getting errors while login using python(Course hero) #Study purpose

Tags: python, automation, python-requests

I tried login in coursehero using python requests module. This is only for learning purpose.

I tried whatever I can understand with the coursehero website structure. But don't know where I am doing wrong. The code below gives 200 status code but still I am not sure the login was successful or not. Dont get any kind of response.

Please help me to log in using python.

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.coursehero.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Mobile Safari/537.366',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
LOGIN = 'https://www.coursehero.com/login/'
data = {
    'url' : LOGIN,
    'email': '#####@gmail.com',
    'password': '###',
    'submit' :'true'
}
req = requests.post("https://www.coursehero.com/api/connect/", headers = headers, data = data, verify=False)
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail? - the subject line says you're "Getting errors "  - what errors?   - you then say you're getting a 200.  Try inspecting the response or using `requests.session()` then hitting a page or API that needs auth to confirm success

Comment: response code is 200, but the issue is a am not getting any HTML data from there or not even any JSON response with post methods. How can I make sure that I am logged in in coursehero? Even I cant access the HTML data so that I can fetch the Recaptcha from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this site works but maybe the response contains cookies that authorise you, and possibly redirects you to the next page (which works for browsers but should be handled manually if you are using some API like this).